# Hide Save button in Component view

Tags: cme, web8.5, gui-extensions

I have a custom GUI extension working that lets me override the Save command (see Rob's article http://www.curlette.com/?p=913).

Ideally I want to hide the button altogether when in the Component UI view - for which there does appear to be a **doHide()** method on the `Tridion.Controls.RibbonButton` itself which works well when I tested in Chrome Dev Tools.

What I can't figure is how to get to the Save button in order to call doHide()?

The following gives me all the controls on the ribbon bar

```
$display.getWindow().$controls.controls["Tridion.Controls.RibbonButton"]
```

Of which an object called UID_63 is the Save button:

[image]

So this works:

```
$display.getWindow().$controls.controls["Tridion.Controls.RibbonButton"].UID_63.doHide();
```

But there must be a nicer way than knowing that UID number?

There is a **hasControl()** method but I can only ever get false out of it:

```
$display.getWindow().$controls.hasControl("SaveBtn");
```

And the **getControl()** method seems to be for adding new controls, not getting current ones?

```
$display.getWindow().$controls.getControl(n, f, i);
```

Cheers

Comment: You could iterate all the controls like this: `var controls = $display.getView().getWindow().$controls.getAllControls("Tridion.Controls.RibbonButton")`. And then: `for (var key in controls)
{
   var id = controls[key].getId();
   if (id == "SaveBtn")
   {  
        controls[key].doHide();
   }
}`

I'm sure there's a more elegant way to solve this, but this might be a good start

Comment: And yes, there is indeed: `$display.getView().getWindow().$controls.getControl($("#SaveBtn"), "Tridion.Controls.RibbonButton").doHide()` :)

Comment: Thanks Albert - it appeared to be the passing of the param as $("#SaveBtn") was something I missed. Make that at answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a hold of the Save Button like this:

`$display.getView().getWindow().$controls.getControl($("#SaveBtn"), "Tridion.Controls.RibbonButton").doHide()`

Comment: Thanks Albert - more rep for you here if you're interested! https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18697/hooking-into-events-on-item-toolbar-in-component-view