# Hooking into events on Item Toolbar in Component View

Tags: web8.5, gui-extensions, content-manager

I have a small GUI extension that is hiding the Save button on the component view ([thanks to Albert Romkes](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/18663/hide-save-button-in-component-view)).

It works great, upon loading the Save button is gone - but - after loading, if you interact with the main item toolbar (click Organise for example) the Save button returns.

[image]

I'm assuming I need to hook into the events of the toolbar and re-trigger my hide function when a user clicks on one of the links but I can't find the right event to hook into.

Currently I have the following (shortened for brevity):

```
Company.Extensions.HideSaveCommand = function HideSaveCommand() {
    Type.enableInterface(this, "Company.Extensions.HideSaveCommand");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Cme.Command", ["HideSaveCommand"]);

    $evt.addEventHandler($display, "start", this._onDisplayStarted);
};

Company.Extensions.HideSaveCommand.prototype._onDisplayStarted = function HideSaveCommand$_onDisplayStarted() 
{
    console.log("_onDisplayStarted called");
    $evt.removeEventHandler($display, "start", this._onDisplayStarted); 

    var item = $display.getItem();
    if (item) {
        if (item.getItemType() == "tcm:16") {                   
            var tabs = $display.getView().getWindow().$controls.getControl($("#ItemToolbar"), "Tridion.Controls.TabControl")
            if(typeof tabs !== "undefined"){
                tabs.addEventListener("click", function(t) { 
                    console.log("CLICKED" + t);
                    this.doHide();                  
                });
                tabs.addEventListener("switch", function(t) { 
                    console.log("switch" + t);
                    this.doHide();                  
                });             
                tabs.addEventListener("select", function(t) { 
                    console.log("select" + t);
                    this.doHide();                  
                });             
            };
        }
    }
}
```

There's no error in the console, but I never see any log when switching between items in the toolbar. I've debugged and know that `tabs` is set to the tab control, but I'm happy to rewrite if there's a better way to achieve what I'm after!

Answer (score 6):

OK - the issue was my incorrect assumption that the Item Toolbar was of type **Tridion.Controls.TabControl**, when it is in fact **Tridion.Controls.RibbonToolbar**!

The following line:

```
var tabs = $display.getView().getWindow().$controls.getControl($("#ItemToolbar"), "Tridion.Controls.TabControl")
```

Had to become:

```
var tabs = $display.getView().getWindow().$controls.getControl($("#ItemToolbar"), "Tridion.Controls.RibbonToolbar")
```

Cheers